# OneDrive authentication using ADAL4J

Tags: java, authentication, onedrive, adal, adal4j

The [Active Directory Authentication Library for Java](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) (ADAL4J) allows authentication via access token to the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/), using the following (simplified) code:

```
public String authenticate(String authorizationUrl, String clientId, String clientSecret) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authorizationUrl, false, service);
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(“https://graph.microsoft.com”, credential, null);
    return future.get().getAccessToken();
}
```

The above works for certain parts of Graph (e.g., for accessing `Office 365` accounts), but does not work for `OneDrive`, where it returns an access token that does not have proper authorization.

Acquiring an access token via [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) works as expected, with the following parameters:

```
authorizationUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
accessTokenUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
clientId: <the clientId for the application>
clientSecret: <the clientSecret for the application> 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
state: <empty>
```

More specifically, running the above in [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) returns an access token with additional scopes, including `https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All`. Using that access token in the `Java` application that calls the `authenticate()` method above, does work, e.g. it lists the contents of the root directory using `/me/drive/root/children` as the REST path.

If, however, the access token returned by the `authenticate()` method is used, an error is returned by `OneDrive`. Removing the user name (`me`) from the path returns only 1 file name, if the specific tenant ID is used instead of `common` in the authorizationUrl.

There seems to be no way to add a scope value in `ADAL4J` and numerous other variations either result in an error, or in getting back 1 file (probably from a different context).

**Is there any way to get a fully authorized access token via ADAL4J, for OneDrive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different permissions: one is application permission, the other is delegated permission.

*"Delegated" permissions, which specify scope-based access using delegated authorization from the signed-in resource owner, are presented to the resource at run-time as "scp" claims in the client's access token.*

*"Application" permissions, which specify role-based access using the client application's credentials/identity, are presented to the resource at run-time as "roles" claims in the client's access token.*

When you get token from POSTMAN for the first time, you will be asked to provide your credentials. In this way, you will get a token with delegated permission, which represents the account. So that, you can call the Graph API under /me.

However, the java code you used to get token can only get an access token with application permission. The application does not have a user identity, as a result, you will get an error while call the Graph API under /me.  With application permission, you can only call the Graph API as /users/{user-id}

**Solution:**

You can get an access token with delegated permission in Java as following:

A) Create an app with public client platform

[image]

B) Add necessary Graph API permission, and grant admin consent for your tenant

[image]

C) Get token

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
AuthenticationContext context = null;
try {
    context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "TENANT_ID", false, service);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", "client_id", "username", "password",null);
    System.out.println( future.get().getAccessToken());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    service.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: I had done all these in various combinations, including the “Grant admin consent”. Anyway, I tried once more with an authorization URL that has the specific tenantId (instead of “common”, albeit I had also tried that), for the same app, using the same clientId and clientSecret (instead of username and password) in the authenticate() method I posted above, and it works. Not sure what was happening, but you deserve most of the credit, so +1 and accepted answer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: The issue was that the "common" tenant references a different drive than the specific tenant, hence the discrepancy with the results.